# How does $f: X\rightarrow W$ in the Theorem 6 satisfy Def. 8(b) "If $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, z) \in f$, then y=z"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition 8**. Let X and Y be sets. A function from X to Y is a triple (f, X, Y), where f is a relation from X to Y satisfying
>   (a) Dom(f) = X.
>   (b) If (x, y)$\in f$ and (x, z) $\in f$, then y=z.
>   We shall adhere to the custom of writing f: $X\space \rightarrow Y$ instead of (f, X, Y) and $y=f(x)$ instead of $(x,\space y) \in f$.

In the following theorem 6, I understand that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $f: X \rightarrow W$ have the same domain $Dom(f)=\{x\in X | ∃y \in Y, f(x) = y\}=X$.

**But how does $f: X\rightarrow W$ in the Theorem 6 satisfy Def. 8(b) "If $(x, y) \in f$ and $(x, z) \in f$, then y=z"**?

> **Theorem 6**. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function and let $W$ be a set containing the image of $f$.. Then $f: X \rightarrow W$ is a function.
>   [Proof] We first prove that $f$ is a relation from X to W.
>    $(x, y) \in f \Rightarrow x \in X \land y \in Im(f)$   $∵\text{Def. of}\space Im(f)$
>   $\Rightarrow x \in X \land y \in W$     $∵Im(f) ⊆ W$
>   $\Rightarrow (x, y) \in X × W$             $∵Def. 1$
>
> Therefore $(x, y) \in f \Rightarrow (x, y) \in X×W$.
>   This proves that $f⊆X×W$.; in other words, $f$ is a relation from $X$ to $W$. Now since $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a function. $Dom(f) = X$ and condition $(b)$ of Definition 8 is satisfied. Therefore, $f: X \rightarrow W$ is a function.

Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T.Lin

[Added: It seems as **given $f: X\rightarrow Y$, (a) Dom(f) = X means 1. For every element $x \in X$, there is an element $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$**]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFtvF.png)

Source: Discrete Mathematics with Applications. Susanna S. Epp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f : X → Y$ and $f : X → W$ have the same domain $Dom(f)$ and the premise of the Theorem says that $Im(f) \subseteq W$.

Thus, the first part of the proof shows that $f \subseteq X \times W$ is a *relation* from $X$ to $W$.

But $f$ satisfy the point (b) of the definition of *function*, i.e. for all $x \in X$ the corrisponding $f(x) \in Im(f)$ is *unique*.

If we "enlarge" $Im(f)$ to $W$, nothing changes: the "images" of elements of $X$ under $f$ are already all into $Im(f)$.

---

About *domain*, see page 65:

> $Dom(\mathcal R) = \{ a \in A \mid (a,b) \in \mathcal R  \text { for some b } \in B \}$

A *relation* $\mathcal R ⊆ A \times B$ is not necessarily defined for every $a∈A$. Consider e.g. the relation "a is father of b" between human males: not every male is father of someone.

Thus we consider as domain of $\mathcal R$ the subset of $A$ of all and only those elements of $A$ that have some "corresponding" element in $B$.

*Functions* are relations that satisfy two additional conditions [see page 73] and we say that $f$ is a *function from* $X$ to $Y$ when

> *(i)* $Dom(f)=X$;

and:

> *(ii)* for every, $x,y,z$, if $(x,y) ∈ f$ and $(x,z) ∈ f$, then $y=z$.

A function is "trivially" defined for every element of its *domain*, simply because $Dom(f)$ is defined as the set of those elements $x$ for which $(x,y) \in f$.